# Shopify String Replace Array not working

Tags: arrays, string, replace, shopify

I am new to shopify but upon my research... this code should work.

```
{% assign dcor = "decor, decors, Decor, Decors" | split: ", "%}
{% assign dcors = "décor, décors, Décor, Décors" | split: ", "%}
{{ product.title | replace: 'dcor', 'dcors' }}
```

But no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Won't work. You can't match/replace elements from arrays. You have to manually replace each variation

```
{% assign dcor = "decor, decors, Decor, Decors" | split: ", "%}
{% assign dcors = "décor, décors, Décor, Décors" | split: ", "%}
{% assign d = dcor.size | minus: 1 %}
{% for i in (0..d) %}
{% assign title = product.title | replace: dcor[i],dcors[i] %}
{% endfor %}
{{ title }}
```